# how to import yahoo/gmail contacts to android app?

Tags: android

I want to send email from ymail/gmail in my app , i m using java mail to send the email how can i import my ymail/gmail contacts, so that i can choose to send whom to mail or not.

Like on a button click it shows me my ymail/gmail contacts.. i am currently doing this thing

```
 final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

               try {   
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("EMAIL","PASSWORD");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                            "This is Body",   
                            "SENDER",   
                            "RECIIPIENTS");   
                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using [android oauth full example with source](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html) (just for gmail contacts)